# Can't detect Database used by JPA with JBoss

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jboss

Probably it is a lack of knowledge but I can't detect which database my application is using.
The datasources and drivers in my **standalone.xml** from JBoss AS look like this:

```html
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS_Pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studadmin</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                    <timeout>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
                        <query-timeout>600</query-timeout>
                    </timeout>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

And this is my **persistence.xml**:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation=" 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
 
 <persistence-unit name="primary">
  <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/studadminDS</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
   <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
 
</persistence>
```

I am simply using this method to read from the database:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    students = new ListDataModel<Student>();
    students.setWrappedData(em.createNamedQuery("SelectStudents")
            .getResultList());
}
```

And this one to persist the student in the database:

```
public String saveStudent() {
    try {
        utx.begin();
    } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    student = em.merge(student);
    em.persist(student);
    students.setWrappedData(em.createNamedQuery("SelectStudents")
            .getResultList());
    try {
        utx.commit();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "studentList";
}
```

After I save some new students in my database, using the corresponding facelet, they are listed successfully. But the problem is, when I look up in my MySQL database, there are no new entries, although the data is persisted somewhere, because if I deploy my application, the data is still available.

So is it obviously which database my application is using or is it possible to detect it?

Comment: are you sure that your transactions are committed?

Comment: I think so, as the data is available, after I redeploy my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up JNDI names.

Your standalone.xml is creating a JNDI name `java:/MySqlDS` , but in the persistence.xml you reference a JNDI resource `java:jboss/datasources/studadminDS`.

I would suggest you change the standalone.xml:

```
...
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/studadminDS" pool-name="MySqlDS_Pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
...
```

It might also be helpful to declare a hibernate dialect in your standalone.xml:

```
     <datasource ...>
           <connection-property name="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </connection-property>
      </datasource ...>
```

Comment: If I do this and start my JBoss Server it gives me the following error: "Service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.studadminDS is already registered" and when I deploy and call my application in browser it fails with the error message "The requested resource (/studadmin/index.jsf) is not available."

Comment: This means that you registered java:jboss/datasources/studadminDS anywhere else. Do you have a hibernate.properties file or a hibernate.cfg.xml? This does also explain, why you could start your app without any errors.

Comment: You're right! As I am using Maven the datasource is also defined in my studadmin-ds.xml and it was using the build-in H2-database by default. So I just commented the whole datasource entry and it works now with my MySQL database by default. Thank you very much for helping me!